# IOS 8 App using Parse isn't working after update

Tags: swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

After updating Cocoapods with Terminal I am getting this error whilst running my application:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B517BAAD-15BD-4CB6-A2AC-F8EA0C3471B4/Neigborfood.app/Neigborfood
Expected in: flat namespace in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B517BAAD-15BD-4CB6-A2AC-F8EA0C3471B4/Neigborfood.app/Neigborfood
```

I am only using the 'ParseUI' pod and have tried deleting all Podfiles and installing them again, only to keep coming up with this error.

The code is in swift with a bridging header for obj-c.

I would be grateful for any help/advice! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, instead of just installing the pod 'ParseUI' also install pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'